# How to add new toolbar item in Window-builder editor in eclipse(ex. copy, paste...)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I am trying to extend windows builder toolbar.I searched a lot but just found this: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/NewComponentsTutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Outside the fact you do not ask for any question, any google request or basic tutorial will guide you to such thing.

Comment: I got the solution to add item into toolbar on eclipse. Thank you.